# SwiftUI Button: Error Argument passed to call that takes no arguments

Tags: swiftui

in the following view I am getting the error "Argument passed to call that takes no arguments" with the buttons and I am not sure why
i copied the file into a new project, somehow in the old Xcode Project it is working but in this one it isn't

I saw that a VSTACK can only fit 10 items but there are less than 10, also I tried removing some items but it isn't working either

maybe someone knows why

this it the view:

````
var body: some View {
        VStack{
            NavigationLink(destination: ShowQRCodeView(eventid: self.id), isActive: $isShowingQRView) {
                EmptyView()}
          
                Image(uiImage: finalProfilePicture)
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 90, height: 90, alignment: .center)
                    .cornerRadius(50)
                Text("\(self.nameOfEvent)")
       

            Divider()
            ////////////////////////////////////   ////////////////////////////////////   ////////////////////////////////////   ////////////////////////////////////   ////////////////////////////////////
    
            ScrollView{
                ImageGrid(images: viewModel.retrievedEventImages)
            }.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
        
            ////////////////////////////////////   ////////////////////////////////////   ////////////////////////////////////   ////////////////////////////////////   ////////////////////////////////////
            
                .toolbar(content: {
                    //Plus to add image
                    ToolbarItem(){
                        NavigationLink {
                            ChoosingImageView(id: self.id)
                        } label: {
                            Image(systemName: "plus")
                                .foregroundColor(Color("Yellow_text"))
                        }
                    }//end toolbarItem1
                    
                    ToolbarItem(){
                        Menu(content: {
                           Button(action: {
                                isShowingQRView = true
                            }, label: {
                                Text("Show QR-Code")
                                Image(systemName: "list.bullet")})
                            .foregroundColor(Color("Yellow_text"))
                            Button(action: {
                                isMainView.toggle()
                                Task {
                                    try? await viewModel.deleteEvent(id: self.id)
                                }
                            }, label: {
                                Text("Delete event")
                                Image(systemName: "trash")
                                    .foregroundColor(Color("Yellow_text"))
                            })
                            
                        }, label:  {
                            Label("PDF", systemImage: "list.bullet")
                                .foregroundColor(Color("Yellow_text"))
                        })
                    }//end toolbarItem2
                })//end toolbar
        
        }//end VStack
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
        .onAppear{
            Task {
                try? await viewModel.retrievePP(helloid: self.id)
                try? await viewModel.retrieveAllPicturesFromFirebase(helloid: self.id)
                try? await viewModel.getName(id: self.id)
                try? await viewModel.getEvents()
            }
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isMainView, content: HomeView.init)
        .simpleToast(isPresented: $showNetworkAlert, options: toast, onDismiss: nil){
            HStack{
                Image(systemName: "wifi.exclamationmark")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                Text("No network connection")
            }
        }

        }//end body
    ```
````

Comment: What line causes the error?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson the buttons, sorry I forgot to mention it